# Existence of trees with height $\kappa$, every level has at most size $\lambda$ and has at least $\lambda^{+}$ maximal branches

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, trees

Definitions A tree means a set-theoretic tree, that is a poset $(T,<)$ so that for each $x\in T$, the set $\{y\in T\mid y<x\}$ is well-ordered.
A $\kappa$-Kurepa tree is a tree of height $\kappa$, each level has at most $< \kappa$ many elements and has at least $\kappa^{+}$-many maximal branches.
Question: I would like to know if there are any results about trees with height $\kappa$, each level of it has at most $\lambda$ elements and with at least $\lambda^{+}$-many maximal branches, where $\kappa \leq \lambda < \aleph_{\omega_{1}}$
I think of those trees as a generalization of $\kappa$-Kurepa trees, where we allow larger levels and more maximal branches.
Is the existence of such trees consistent with ZFC? Is the negation of their existence consistent with ZFC?
Where can I find some more results for such trees?

Comment: Is this intended to be a sort of generalisation of a Susin tree?

Comment: No, it is not a generalization of Suslin trees. It is more like a generalization of Kurepa trees, but I don't know if there are any results for them.

Comment: Just take a model where $2^{<\kappa}\leq\lambda$ and $2^\kappa>\lambda$.

Comment: @MonroeEskew In fact I could see that, but I have no clue if the negation is consistent.

Comment: The negation can be forced with Mitchell forcing up to an inaccessible, for example for $\kappa=\lambda=\omega_1$.